# awk/sed: add a count of the occurrences of a match string to a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

so I have a file, and there is a string that I want to highlight by put a marker line above it.  I can do this easily enough with sed:

```
cat flog.txt |sed '/foo/ i===========B' >t.lis
```

this works fine, as I have a file that looks like this now

```
===========B
blablabla foo blabla bla
bla bla bla
===========B
blablabla foo blabla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla 
===========B
blablabla foo blabla bla
bla bla bla
===========B
blablabla foo blabla bla
bla bla bla
```

however I want the "=========B" line to have a count 1, 2, 3, etc.  so the file looks like this instead:

```
===========B 1
blablabla foo blabla bla
bla bla bla
===========B 2
blablabla foo blabla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla 
===========B 3
blablabla foo blabla bla
bla bla bla
===========B 4
blablabla foo blabla bla
bla bla bla
```

and so on, can anybody help?

thanks,

Comment: what if there are more than one match per line?

Comment: Does `barfoobar` match `foo` or not? What if you were searching for `f.o` and the input contained `foo` - would that match? Just trying to figure out if you want a partial or full word match and if you want a string or regexp match.

Comment: 1) I only want 1 marker no matter how many matches are on the line, 
2) barfoobar is a match.

Answer (score 5):

This `awk` should do the job:

```
awk '/foo/{ print "===========B " ++i } 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of match you want:

Partial regexp match:

```
awk '/foo/{ print "===========B", ++i } 1' file
```

Full regexp match with POSIX awk:

```
awk '(" "$0" ") ~ /[[:space:]]foo[[:space:]]/{ print "===========B", ++i } 1' file
```

Full regexp match with GNU awk:

```
awk '/\<foo\>/{ print "===========B", ++i } 1' file
```

Partial string match:

```
awk 'index($0,"foo"){ print "===========B", ++i } 1' file
```

Full string match:

```
awk 'index(" "$0" ","[[:space:]]foo[[:space:]]"){ print "===========B", ++i } 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't handle multiple matches but aligns the marker to the matched token

```
$ awk 'match($0,"foo"){m=sprintf("%*s",RSTART," "); gsub(" ","=",m); print m"B "++c}1' file

==============================B 1
asfa lkja ldfkjal jlajsd lja foo
=========B 2
asdf af foo afa sdf foo  asdfasdf
=================B 3
asdfad asdfasdf foo
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
sed -E '/foo/{x;s/.*/expr & + 1/e;x;G;s/^(.*)\n(.*)/============B \2\n\1/}' file
```

Keep a counter in the hold space. Increment the counter each time there is a match, append the counter to the current matching line and using pattern matching, rearrange into the desired result.